# Is it technically correct to call hard disk drives or an SSD, also RAM memory types (Random Access Memory)

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, storage, terminology

In computer jargon, is it correct to call drives of various types (e.g. hard disk, SSD, DVD) a type of random access memory (RAM)?

From what I understand RAM is a device that holds information that can be read and also written or erased, as opposed to Read Only Memory (ROM), which can only be read.

According to this definition, hard disk drives, floppy disk drives and solid state drives are also RAM.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct,  It's random access versus sequential access.  It's memory versus peripherals. Hard Disk Drives, floppy disk drives and SSDs are random-access peripherals.

Comment: @journeyman-geek a question about disambiguating common computer terminology isn't within scope?

Comment: Kinda fails the practical problem test, lacks research effort, imo is a low quality question...   I don't see any real argument for keeping this question open

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I think this question has merit. A nuanced answer would be "it depends". I'll try to clean it up a bit more.

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: "RAM" is a word and words have meanings. It so happens that the word "RAM" originated as an acronym for "random access memory", but it now has a slightly different meaning than those three words do. This is *very* common in English for acronyms that are not names. That you can understand how a word is or should be used based on its origin is considered a fallacy in linguistics. Meanings drift over time and that is a good thing -- otherwise we'd be stuck with words with obsolete meanings.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is this correct?

No.

> **A random-access memory device allows data items to be read or written in almost the same amount of time irrespective of the physical location of data inside the memory.**
>
> In contrast, with other direct-access data storage media such as hard disks, CD-RWs, DVD-RWs and the older magnetic tapes and drum memory, the time required to read and write data items varies significantly depending on their physical locations on the recording medium, due to mechanical limitations such as media rotation speeds and arm movement.

Source [Random-access memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory)

Comment: so the opposite of Read only memory should be direct access memory and not random access memory. Ram is not used in opposition with ROM in this case then?

Comment: @yoyo_fun The opposite of ROM is any kind of memory that is writable.

Comment: In theory you could make a hard drive with constant read/write times for all sectors.

Comment: @jiggunjer So then the hard drive would be random access, but not memory? Would it be random access storage?

Comment: @yoyo_fun that sounds more precise. The difference between a drive and memory isn't technology, it is the usage purpose. You can have a virtual ram drive that isn't memory. Your hdd can have a page file that can be considered part of memory. The word memory can also refer to physical storage technology like flash and magnetic tapes, but the semantics are different. The difference between RA and sequential isn't technology either , it is algorithmic time.

Comment: @jiggunjer *" The difference between a drive and memory isn't technology, it is the usage purpose"* -- No, it's more than just purpose because there is a functional difference.  The memory of the computer must be word (or even byte) addressable.  Mass-storage devices, in order to achieve their capacity goal, are only block addressable.  An HDD cannot replace the memory.  *"Your hdd can have a page file that can be considered part of memory."* -- That's pure semantics or a high-level perspective of virtual memory, and not an operational or functional description of how a page file works.

Comment: @sawdust  "*it's more than just purpose because there is a functional difference*" -- incorrect. You observe a correlation and assume it affects the definition. But the functional differences are just correlations caused by electrical engineering optimization. I am talking about abstract memory and storage. Implementation details do not *define* the semantics of storage and memory. Currently, memory is byte or word addressable but *it doesn't have to be* in the abstract. The word size can change, it could be bit-addressable, these are implementation details.

Comment: @sawdust I think we agree on some level. But the functional difference is merely a consequence of their distinct purposes. Semantically they are different based on purpose, as a correlative in practice this means they require different interfacing with the cpu. But s & m  are not different *because* they have different interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good explanation to my question after searching online more.

The term RANDOM ACCESS in RAM acronym is opposed to SEQUENTIAL ACCESS that is found in other types of memory devices such as magnetic tape, magnetic drive, HDD, optical drive, etc. In those situations it is necessary to go through other memory locations to access the desired location.

As opposed to sequential access, random access memory devices allow the data on them to be accessed at random locations without the need to go through other locations first, such as the situation where on a Hard Disk Drive it is necessary to spin the magnetic drive all the way to the location that is wanted.

The explanation I found is in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FAgmvJZhOI

So a Hard Disk Drive may not be considered a RAM device, but an SSD can in theory be considered a form of random access memory.

Comment: No, you are still wrong because you are conflating memory with mass-storage peripherals. HDD is a random access device. An example of sequential-access memory is bubble memory. Neither HDD or SSD are  form(s) of memory; they are mass-storage peripherals.

Comment: @sawdust I think the terms are used both ways. According to wikipedia storage devices are also considered forms of computer memory. But I understand what you want to say. According to von Neuman architecture HDD,SSD and other devices are not computer memory per se.

Comment: The distinction between primary and secondary memory isn't required by a von Neumann system. I think people take computer semantics for granted by saying memory differs from storage. This question is good for considering some implicit assumptions.

Comment: @jiggunjer Isn't ROM also storage and not memory? What is actually memory, if we do not consider von Neuman architecture?

Comment: @yoyo_fun *"I think the terms are used both ways"* -- And you can be wrong too.  If you're so positive, then why are you asking questions?  If you want to broadly define *"memory"* as "hardware that holds/retains data", then go ahead and include HDDs and SSDs.  Then see  how well that helps (or hinders) your understanding of computer systems, and your communication with professionals in the field/industry.

Comment: @yoyo_fun most modern ROM is actually NVRAM with less write cycles. Even though the M stands for memory, it is not always used as "working memory" (but sometimes it is, some firmware runs on pure eeprom). The word memory is semantically overloaded.

Comment: So to answer your question, in practice ROM is sometimes memory, sometimes storage, sometimes both. In theory a custom computer could switch around hdd and ram so it runs programs on the hard disk and stores files on formatted RAM. Obviously, this would make for a very useless computer :). In such a case the second "d" from hd**d** would be omitted, since it is now hdm. The ram would possibly be renamed RAD or RAMD :p

Comment: @jiggunjer *"In theory a custom computer could switch around hdd and ram ...:* -- There is no such theory.  The interface to RAM (aka main memory) is special in a computer.  It requires only a single machine instruction to read or write a RAM location.  HDD or SSD (or any mass-storage peripheral) requires many instructions (aka a device driver) to read a block of data and then fetch that one word/byte out of that block.

Comment: @sawdust obviously there is such a theory, by definition, since I stated it. But it is a purely hypothetical situation, no-one will redesign motherboards and controller chips anytime soon. My point was the technology (e.g. flash) doesn't limit the application, our current designs are merely striving for optimal performance and utility. Engineers made the **choice** to use SDRAM and single instructions for accessing it. But e.g. a company could create (very slow) RAM based on magnetic disk technology that slots into motherboards. Again, hypothetically speaking.